# Making a data frame of only outliers of a large data set

Tags: r, dataframe, outliers

Instead of trying to remove outliers from a data set, I am trying to create a new data frame consisting only of the rows tha have outliers in them.

I was able to column-bind the averages and standard deviations of the different groups onto the end  of the data set. Now, I have tried this code to produce a table of outlier data:

```
Outliers <- Sample[((Sample$x - Sample$Averages)/Sample$StDevs) > 2.00,]
```

This process runs, but produces an empty table for Outliers. I tested some individual values from the data  to make sure outliers existed, and they do. If I specify a row, the above calculation   indeed produces a Boolean argument. It is when I try to collect these outliers in a table that   I have problems. I also tried initializing Outliers as a data.frame or data.table, but was unsuccessful  here as well (probably just because I am new  to R).

ex:
When I run

```
((Sample$x[3] - Sample$Averages[3])/Sample$StDevs[3]) > 2
```

it returns TRUE. This is good. Why, then, do I get an empty table of outliers when I simply want to KEEP everything in Sample where this condition is true? I do not feel that this should be a difficult problem, but I cannot for the life of me get it to work.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless you post  results of `str(Sample)` we have no way of determining what the source of your error might be. Post more code and data.

Comment: all of the data is private. However, I will add an edit to try to explain further what I have tried.

Comment: perhaps the simplest version of my question is: How do I initialize a data frame without knowing how many rows it will end up having, (it will have the same amount of columns as 'Sample').

Comment: `Sample[ 0, ]` should get you an empty dataframe with no rows and the same column names

Comment: I am not sure how to close out a question on this site, yet, but just to save anyone unnecessary trouble, my issue has been resolved. Thank you, everyone, for your input!

Comment: You could just check that as an answer (or you could have posted your own.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sample[ 0, ]` should get you an empty dataframe with no rows and the same column names.